# Owin.startup not calling while running from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, owin

In my AzureAD Owin Web Application working while running IIS Express but not working in local iis

I have added Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.4.0.1 to project and added

Startup Project

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(AzureTest.Startup))]

namespace AzureTest
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        // The Client ID is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD.
        string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
        // RedirectUri is the URL where the user will be redirected to after they sign in.
        string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];
        // Tenant is the tenant ID (e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or 'common' for multi-tenant)
        static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];
        // Authority is the URL for authority, composed by Azure Active Directory v2 endpoint 
        // and the tenant name (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0)
        string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);
        // Scopes are the specific permissions we are requesting for the application.
        string scopes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Scopes"];
        // ClientSecret is a password associated with the application in the authority. 
        // It is used to obtain an access token for the user on server-side apps.
        string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];

        string resourceID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResourceId"];

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUr,ClientSecret as obtained from web.config
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                    Authority = authority,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false // This is a simplification
                    },
                    // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
        {
            var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

            string[] scopes = this.scopes.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

            var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();

            GenUtil.token = result.AccessToken;
        }
    }
}
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Web;


namespace AzureTest
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string model = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["model"];
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                   new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                   OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
            else
            {
                ValidateToken(GenUtil.token);
            }
        }
        public JwtSecurityToken ValidateToken(string token)
        {
            //string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";

            ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(model, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());

            OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;

            TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,
                ValidateLifetime = false
            };

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokendHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            SecurityToken jwt = null;

            var result = tokendHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out jwt);

            return jwt as JwtSecurityToken;
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="None"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientId" value="7879c3a4-4d66-48c8-988b-xxxxx" />
    <add key="redirectUri" value="http://localhost:65338" />
    <add key="model" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="]:Al1X:XnVSejwT:pUDjrxxxxx" />
    <add key="Tenant" value="xxxx.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="Authority" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" />
    <add key="Scopes" value="User.Read" />
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true"/>
    <add key="owin:appStartup" value="AzureTest.Startup"/>
  </appSettings>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Package

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.17.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Identity.Client" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.11" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

Expectation is this code should run in Local IIS, also I am facing issue in Validate Token, it is also not working properly, it showing signature error.

Comment: Can you use the access token to access your service?

Comment: Yes, I want to pass token to my Service and it should be validated their. I am facing to issues 1. ASP.Net Web application not authenticating on IIS. 2. Token validation showing signature not valid error. Can you please help me for solving it?

Comment: If you want to integrate Azure AD with your WebForm application, you can refer to https://forums.asp.net/t/2140446.aspx?Azure+Authentication+using+OAuth+in+ASP+NET+WebForms+NOT+MVC